# MYSQL prevent duplicates in a specific table field

Tags: mysql, duplicates

i am new to mysqli and am querying a table named movies and movie comments. I am trying to get a feed of movies which are ordered by which movie had the most recent comment. This is the code I am currently using:

```
select movies.id, movies.movie_title, movies.movie_description, movies.movie_url, movies.movie_actors, movies.movie_thumbnail, movies.time_uploaded, movies.movie_categories from movie_comments left join movies on movie_comments.movies_id = movies.id where movie_status=1 ORDER BY movie_comments.time_posted DESC LIMIT 10;
```

The problem I am having is that if a comment has two comments, it will get the same movie twice, as it has two registered comment counts illustrated by the image below:

[image]

As you can see, the first column, id, has duplicates (in this case, id 129). Any idea how I can modify the query to prevent duplicate results from coming up in the ID field? The table in the db that contains these duplicates are in the movie_comments, and the field is called movies_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a row for each comment, as that is the table you're selecting from, instead, you could aggregate your results, so something like:

```
SELECT      m.id, 
            m.movie_title, 
            m.movie_description, 
            m.movie_url, 
            m.movie_actors, 
            m.movie_thumbnail, 
            m.time_uploaded, 
            m.movie_categories 

FROM        movie_comments mc

LEFT JOIN   movies m
    ON      mc.movies_id = movies.id 

WHERE       movie_status=1 

GROUP BY    m.id, 
            m.movie_title, 
            m.movie_description, 
            m.movie_url, 
            m.movie_actors, 
            m.movie_thumbnail, 
            m.time_uploaded, 
            m.movie_categories

ORDER BY    MAX(mc.time_posted) DESC 

LIMIT 10;
```